# Trying to convert Rich Text to HTML with embedded images and file attachments

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I've been reading about some xPages functionality about wrapping a document with DominoDocument.wrap(...) that is supposed to do this for you.  However, I am in a stand along Java program.

Is it possible to get the xPages Jar Files to import into my application somehow?  I do have the basic Notes Jars working.

Answer (score 1):

it is unlikely you will get this working using the DominoDocument class. when you wrap the Document, it creates a 'DominoRichTextItem', during this process it extracts the attachments to the local filesystem so that the web server can easily serve the content during the user's browsing/editing session.
this attachment extraction process relies on the user's session information, as well as the xpages applications 'persistence service'.

you are better of trying to emulate this idea by using the standard notes API to extract the text/html mime part, and the extracting attachments/inline image mime parts for whatever your purpose

Comment: I would love to do that but do not have a clue how.  Do you have any sample code I could look at?  I know nothing about MIME.  =(